# Don't loop code inside foreach bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pdo, foreach

I'm looping through an unknown number of containers which are using the `col-md-8` Bootstrap class. I want to include next to the first iteration a `col-md-4` class to offer up as a sidebar.

I need to pause the loop after the first iteration include my div then carry on looping from where it left off. Is there a php pause for the foreach loop so I can achieve this.

```
<?php  foreach ($news as $new) : ?>
<div class="col-md-8">

</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: use a counter and set it to 0, then use a if clausule to check if counter is 0, if so add the `col-md-4` column, else do nothing.

Comment: Did you try anything? It can be easier (and more valuable for you) to help if you try something, stumble upon a particular difficulty and ask about it, presenting your work.

Comment: What you are asking is literally not possible. Scripts run line-for-line; you can't pause there then go to here then go back to there. VDesign and donald123 below have your solution.

Comment: Yes I did try, I tried putting the div before the foreach and then using the bootstrap push and pull that works but when an col-md-8 is not next to the col-md-4 the rest of the iterations are pulled out of the container. 

I tried putting it in the foreach and using display none and display block on the first child but that's not the right way to go about.

Comment: If you want to make a sidebar you'd better split it up entirely `<div class="col-md-12"><div class="col-md-8"><? // News items loop here ?></div><div class="col-md-4"><? // sidebar here ?></div></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a if-statement

```
<?php  
   $i=1;
   foreach ($news as $new) : ?>
        <div class="col-md-8">

         </div>
        <?php if($i==1):?>
          <div class="col-md-4">

         </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php $i++;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Cleaner to use `if(++$i == 1):`

Comment: @AmazingDreams you're right, but i think the OP is not deep enough in php to understand your line ;)

Comment: This looks good I think I'm understanding it right, run the foreach but when 'i=1' insert the col-md-4 but every iteration increase the value of 'i' so it isn't included every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
 $len = count($news); 
 for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) { 
   if ($i == 0) {
?>
<div class="col-md-4">

</div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="col-md-8">

</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: **for ($i = 0; $i < count($news); $i++)** no good practice to use count() in conditions on each loop count() will be fired up!